# Logback ignore logger of parent package

Tags: java, logging, logback

Logback ignore logger of parent package.

I have those appenders:

**appender**

```
<appender name="fileAppender1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>myLogFile1.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="fileAppender2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>myLogFile2.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

And 3 loggers:

**logger 1**

```
<logger name="my" level="INFO" additivity="false" >
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender1" />
</logger>
```

**logger 2**

```
<logger name="my.test" level="DEBUG" additivity="false" >
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
```

**logger 3**

```
<root level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender2" />
</root>
```

- If I use three of them I get only second logger works. (The most definitive one)
- If I delete `additivity="false"` all loggers write the same info with the same level (highest - INFO)

**How to config** logback that root logger collects and prints through appender all *TRACE* log messages, `my` logger collects and prints all *DEBUG* messages of package `my` without package `my.test` and `my.test` logger collects and prints all *INFO* messages of package `my.test` and down?

Comment: so you are looking for only trace is fileAppender2  debug in console and info in fileAppender1(for my and subpackages of my) right?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand how to create logger that aggregate all log messages from specific level. Like it is in log4j for logger "root"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Level filter

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
      <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
      <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
</filter>
```

Hence your logback.xml would become

```
<appender name="fileAppender1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>INFO</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
          <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <file>myLogFile1.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="fileAppender2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>TRACE</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
          <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <file>myLogFile2.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>DEBUG</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
          <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="my" level="INFO" additivity="false" >
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender1" />
</logger>

<logger name="my.test" level="DEBUG" additivity="false" >
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>

<root level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender2" />
</root>
```

**UPDATE**

If you need ERROR and WARN use the ThresholdFilter with WARN(shown below) and if you need info, error and warn use the threshold filter as info(which is I believe default behaviour)

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
    <level>WARN</level>
</filter>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I run this code:

    `package my.study.logback;
    public class MainClass {
        private static final Logger log=LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainClass.class);
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            log.trace("trace");
            log.debug("debug");
            log.info("info");
            log.warn("warn");
            log.error("error"); }}`

I get only "info" line in myLogFile1.log. 
P.S. Sorry, for code format

Comment: So you want trace and debug to be ignored and only info, warn and error you need in myLogFile1.log?

Comment: Thank you for you help. I dealt with a question